# windows application Logging mechanism

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library

I am developing a Windows Application. I am displaying log information in the main form. I want to add logging information from another class. Below is the code on a button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDAL dal = new LoadCaseDAL();
        Result result = new Result();
        dal.Load(result);
        AddToLogger("test end");
    }

AddtoLogger(){ }
```

AddtoLogger() and button click event are in main form.

In dal.Load(result) method I am calling this function. I want to add log information in this function to the main form using AddToLogger() method.

```
protected internal void LoadLCFiles(BoltDataset.LoadCaseDataTable dt)
    {
        List<string> files = Helper.GetFiles("Text Files|*.txt");

        **//AddToLogger("Total files: " + files.Count().ToString());**

        Task loadFilesTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (string filePath in files)
            {
                LoadLCTextFile(filePath, dt);
            }
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {

                **//AddToLogger("Loading Failed");**
            }
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
            {                    
                **//AddToLogger("Loading Succesfull");**
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I achieve this ? Kindly suggest.

Comment: pass this in dal.Load(this, result); and make AddtoLogger public.. Now you can  call  AddtoLogger from your dal class... however, for logging i would use something like log4net

Comment: dal isnt a form. its a class for data access layer

Answer (score 0):

You can put your logging function in a static class. That way it will be available everywhere in your code and does not need an object in order to execute it.

```
public static class Tools 
{
    public static void AddToLogger(string msg) { ... }
}
```

Now build a delegate that you call inside `AddToLogger()` everytime you add a message:

```
  // Delegate for new log entries
  public delegate void LogEntryAddedDelegate(string message);
  public static LogEntryAddedDelegate LogEntryAdded { get; set; }
```

Then call it in your `AddToLogger()` function. So your static class should then look something like this:

```
public static class Tools
{
    // Delegate for new log entries
    public delegate void LogEntryAddedDelegate(string message);
    public static LogEntryAddedDelegate LogEntryAdded { get; set; }

    public static void AddToLogger(string msg)
    {
        // Do some stuff here

        // Call the event
        LogEntryAdded(msg);
    }
}
```

Then you can hook to your event in your form like this:

```
// Registers your function to get called when a new log message is added
Tools.LogEntryAdded += new Tools.LogEntryAddedDelegate(NewLogAdded);

protected void NewLogAdded(string msg)
{
    // Update your textbox
}
```

Then you can add new log messages like this:

```
Tools.AddToLogger("msg");
```

This way your function `NewLogAdded()` gets called every time you add a new message to the log.

---

Also you might want to take a look at logging frameworks. They make logging stuff much easier and you don't have to code it on your own.

A good logging library for .Net is [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: But the problem remains. My problem is that I dont have access to the form control which is dislaying log information.

Comment: @ManishGupta Updated my answer with a tutorial on how to achieve that